Pivot in Pyspark and custom sort
enter image description here
I'm trying to pivot some data from a data frame in an specific order (hours in rows and months in columns). It works but I can't sort correctly months. I'm not sure if it's because I extract first the month in number from a column in timestamp format and the convert to string from month in number with a when function.
DF = MonthsDF\ 
    .dropna(subset = ["trip_start_time"])\ 
    .withColumn("Month", F.month("trip_start_time"))\ 
    .withColumn("Month", F.when(F.col("Month") == 1, "JAN")\
    .when(F.col("Month") == 2, "FEB")

I have attached the current output and the desired output along with a link to a sample csv file.
https://mega.nz/file/jYREyTYI#lQ3sobyjK13Z0VIXWhD67gKO0r4rYe37tZfIL2P-bnU
first[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/iVfKGfFj.png)
MyDF = DF.groupBy("Hour").pivot("month").count().orderBy("Hour")


Hi! Could you please post your dataset as reproducible python code rather than an image? Something like df = spark.createDataFrame(     [         (0, 3),         (1, 10),     ],     ["hour", "april"]  )

Hello, thanks for your reply. I've attached a screenshot of the csv file. I thought the problem could be this previous code, but I'm not sure:
DF = MonthsDF
.dropna(subset = ["trip_start_time"])
.withColumn("Mes", F.month("trip_start_time"))
.withColumn("Month",
F.when(F.col("Month") == 1, "JAN")
.when(F.col("Month") == 2, "FEB")\
                   etc

Thanks

Could you please [edit] your question to: (1) include the dataset as reproducible python code rather than as screenshot of a csv file; (2) include your comment about what the problem could be directly in the question, so it would be more readable than in a comment below the question; (3) Surround the code with triple-backquotes `````` so that it displays properly with linebreaks?

you can use the values attribute of .pivot(). e.g., .pivot('month', values=['JAN','FEB']) will create columns with the provided values based on the order provided.

there are too many screenshots hampering the readability of the question. please look into Stef's comment.

@samkart, that worked. Thank you so much.
